# How do I delete the script execution history in google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, logging, ide, privacy

Simple question, but... I wrote my first script and it runs perfect... but, how do I manually delete the script execution history in google scripts?

Answer (score 4):

Wait 7 days.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

> The built-in Apps Script execution log. This log is lightweight and streams in real time, but persists only for a short time.

The execution page shows this:

> Showing n executions over last 7 days